# Creating xr.DataArray with dask.delayed coordinates

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I am trying to create a `xr.DataArray` from the output of `dask.delayed`. Both the data and its coordinates are read from file in the same call to the delayed function, therefore the coordinates are not known until computation happens. Both data and coordinates have `np.nan` lenght, since the length cannot be known until I open the file.

When i try to construct the `DataArray` with:

```
data_array = xr.DataArray(delayed_values, dims=['pulseId'], 
                                          coords=[delayed_coords])
```

xarray triggers the computation on `delayed_coords` and I get this error:

```
ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'pulseId': length nan on the data but length 102 on coordinate 'pulseId'
```

Since the `delayed_values` dimension is still `np.nan` but the coordinates dimension has been computed.

Is there a way to tell xarray not to compute the result for the coordinates and treat it as a delayed array?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the indexing (dimension) coordinates of a DataArray must be known. You can have non-dimension coordinates which are chunked. For exmaple, if your data is in a cartographic projection, you could have the dimensions x, y, which must be known, and the coordinates lat(x, y) and lon(x, y) which could be chunked. does this fit what you're trying to do?

Comment: Oh ok, i think i understand what you mean. I did not know that there could be non-dimension coordinates. Would need to index on those coordinates, so they need to be dimensions, but I see how xarray needs to know them before hand in order to be able to read into the chunked data efficiently. I think I need to restructure the way I load the data... Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could also have 1D unknown non-dimension coordinates, like if you had dimensions `(x, y)` without labels and then coordinates `lat(y), lon(x)` which were chunked. but yeah you couldn't use them to index the data. in most use cases for xarray, you have ≥2 dimensions, so your dimension coordinates are necessarily much smaller than your data. If this is not true for you, maybe consider using `dask.dataframe`?

Comment: Yes using a dataframe is the other thing I was looking into. I have multi dimensional data that would fit better in a xarray. The index is indeed much smaller than the data, but they are stored in the same file. I wanted to optimize and open the file just once, but apparently that will not be possible. I need to make an index first. Thank for your help!